# Remove the function which adds nofollow to links in comments

Tags: comment-form, comments

Not sure where the function is that does this but i need to remove it so all links in comments do not contain the rel="nofollow" attribute.

I know i can use the [comment_text filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_text/) to remove nofollow but thats not what i need to do.

What i need to do is remove the function from WordPress core which then enables me to manually add nofollow to comment links selectively.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your plugin file/theme's functions.php:

```
remove_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wp_rel_nofollow', 15 );
```

You could then add your own filter to `pre_comment_content` to use `wp_rel_nofollow` selectively, based on your criteria.

URLs that are automatically made clickable from plain-text urls like `example.com` aren't filterable in a way that allows removing of the `rel="nofollow"` attribute. The only solution for those is filtering `comment_text` or removing the auto-adding of links entirely:

```
remove_filter( 'comment_text', 'make_clickable', 9 );
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob however i just want to add nofollow to specific links in comments manually.

Comment: My answer will do what you're asking for in terms if turning off the automatic  adding of nofollow, but in terms of adding them you'd just have to edit the comments. I'm not sure how else you'd expect to be able to do that or how that isn't already what you want.

Comment: Only works when adding HTML links with a tags like this <a href="http://example.com">Link</a> but doesn't remove nofollow when adding text links like this http://example.com

Comment: Doesn't appear to be possible to remove it from those without filtering comment_text. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me with WordPress 4.8.1. Not sure why @Dev hasn't accepted your answer.