# Remove rel="nofollow ugc" from links in comments

Tags: comments, nofollow

WordPress automatically adds rel="nofollow ugc" to all links posted in comments. In our case we use comments to link to relevant articles in a website and need them to be followed.

How to remove this automatic rel being added?

The function itself is setup in the core with: wp_rel_ugc()

There are [older posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275790/remove-the-function-which-adds-nofollow-to-links-in-comments) recommending this filter:

remove_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wp_rel_nofollow', 15 );

However that no longer seems to work.

I would like to disable this function altogether.

I looks like some effort was made to fix this in core, but this has not been implemented yet: [Prevent tagging certain links in comments with rel="nofollow ugc"](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53290)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes the tag before it displays the comment on the page. I tested it myself.

```
function remove_ugc_from_links($text) {
    // replace 'rel="ugc"' with an empty string
    $new_text = str_replace('rel="ugc"', '', $text);

    return $new_text;
}
// Hook our function to the 'comment_text' filter
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'remove_ugc_from_links');
```

Comment: Are you sure? I can't find the `wp_rel_ugc` filter in [the online documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/) or the source code.

Comment: I am testing this on a demo site now, I will figure it out for you.

Comment: I just posted a function that works, it removes the tag

Comment: This is working, I had to modify slightly because I wanted to remove nofollow as well:   $new_text = str_replace('rel="nofollow ugc"', '', $text);

Comment: wp_rel_ugc: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_rel_ugc/

Comment: @AJD Yes, I had found that function. The original version of the answer made reference to a `wp_rel_ugc` *filter* which doesn't seem to exist.